# Convert SQL file to XML to upload sample data in wordpress

Tags: sql, xml, wordpress, import, sample-data

I have downloaded my SQL file for my wordpress blog. I need to package it as .xml formart so that the new user of the blog can simply upload the sample content via admin > tool > section.

I don't want him/her to import the SQL file. It's easier to upload the .xml file. What do i do to convert sql t .xml for wordpress?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Joel - I think no need to convert sql to xml. you can directly export your blog data from your wordpress admin as per below :

```
Tools -> Export -> All content
```

It will give you data in xml format.so this file you can import anywhere in other wp sites.